# Create orchard session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms

I need to manipulate with data in separated thread in orchard cms.
Problem is when request ends session and services are disposed.
What is the best way to create db session, or how to manipulate with data after request finish?

EDIT:

I am trying something like this code

`var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            //builder.RegisterInstance(_shellSettings = new ShellSettings { Name = ShellSettings.DefaultName });
            builder.RegisterType<TransactionManager>().As<ITransactionManager>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<SessionFactoryHolder>().As<ISessionFactoryHolder>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

But i don't know what exactly to register, it throws me error when resolving repository.

Comment: Show your effort on solving the issue.

Comment: I think about change lifetime scope of session, but i don't think that is good idea. I think that better would be create new container, but how, where? 
I can try create new container when i start new thread and register instances that i need? is it good approach?

Comment: I think that the best way is to create a background task.

Answer (score 0):

Spawning threads on a web server is bad, it reduces its ability to serve many requests simultaneously. You should consider offloading your task to some other process, like a windows service, communicating through MSMQ by example.

Otherwise consider letting your task instantiates and disposes off the services and sessions it needs itself, instead of using those bounded to the request life-cycle. You may need to setup for this a dedicated dependency resolver letting the task explicitly control the lifetime of the objects it requests to the dependency resolver.